# Scala identify string with pattern matching

Tags: string, scala, casting, any

I wonder how to avoid casting `Any` to `String` but rather use pattern matching.

Having collected a dataframe from spark `like df.select('column).first.toSeq.head`
Direct casting sort of is a workaround  `df.select('column).first.toSeq.head.asInstanceOf[String]`, but 
I would prefer to use scala native pattern matching like

```
val collectedFromSpark: Any = "someString"
  val realString:String = collectedFromSpark match{
    case s:String => _
    case _ => throw new Exception("expected something else")
  }
```

However, `realString:String` only receives `Any` and not `String`.

How can I formulate this cast in a scala native way?

Comment: Does changing your case to `case s: String => s` work?

Comment: yes. That is the solution.

Comment: Note - using `case s: String` is a code smell in Scala since you're making a run-time, i.e. not compile-time, check. I suggest this talk on [Parametricity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtEEZa_Q8Vw).

Comment: So what else would you recommend?

Comment: @KevinMeredith When you have an object of type `Any`, you cannot avoid the runtime check. I would say the real code smell here, is that there is an object of type `Any` in the first place.

Comment: @marstran how could I do that in spark as a `df.select('column).as[String].collect.toSeq.head` strangely still seemed to resolve to any

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Spark. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your case to this:

```
case s: String => s
```

Now it will know that `s` is a `String`.